# org-mode hotkeys not working (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, virtualbox, org-mode

I have an Ubuntu virtualbox setup for development. When I am in org-mode in a file, none of the hotkeys for org-mode work (e.g. `M-RETURN` to create a new headline). What can I do to get these to work? I've never had this happen with my work setup (OSX, Centos)

Comment: I occassionally have run into the problem that a linux windows manager (such as xfce) will use the alt key for its own purposes, and messes up the emacs mappings for M- . Perhaps something like that is happening for you? Presumably there is some sort of "keyboard" setting in gnome that might be hogging the M- key?

Comment: Yeah I am getting this, but I am not sure how to fix it. I turned off the option to use alt hotkeys in the Terminal menu but I believe it is still causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

At first try if `Esc-RETURN` works. If so, emacs doesn't understand your meta-key.

If it still doesn't work, I would do the following. Open my org file. Then press `C-h m`.

Your window should be split and a buffer describing all the current active modes should appear. Check if org-mode is the major-mode.

Comment: Very weird, I thought alt was my only meta key (and it works for stuff like M-v). However it registered Esc-Return and gave the expected headline. How do I set this to Alt?